# Java parameter in constructor issue with class modifier

Tags: java

My constructor keeps giving an error at `public Customer(String initName)` with:

> a { expected.

Here's my code:

```java
public class CustomerConstructorTestProgram {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Customer c1, c2, c3;
        // Create Bob
        c1 = new Customer("Bob");
        c1.name = "Bob";
        c1.age = 17;
        c1.money = 10;
        // Create Dottie
        c2 = new Customer("Dottie");
        c2.name = "Dottie";
        c2.age = 3;
        c2.money = 0;
        // Create blank customer
        c3 = new Customer("Jane");

        public Customer(String initName) {
            name = initName;
            age = 0;
            money = 0.0f;
        }



        System.out.println("Bob looks like this: " + c1.name + ", " +
                c1.age + ", " + c1.money);
        System.out.println("Dottie looks like this: " + c2.name + ", "
                + c2.age + ", " + c2.money);
        System.out.println("Customer 3 looks like this: " + c3.name +
                ", " + c3.age + ", " + c3.money);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks weird: it seems that you are trying to write the `Customer` constructor in the middle of the `main()` method. You cannot do that. Place the `Customer` constructor in the `Customer` class definition.

Comment: Where should I put the class

Comment: _Where should I put the class_ ... either inside your current class `CustomerConstructorTestProgram` as `static class Customer` or into a separate class file `Customer.java`. – However, I suggest you work through a proper Java tutorial, see the [Official Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and Stack Overflow's [`java` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) for further pointers.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `Customer` class has to be properly decalred (the class `Customer` doesn't exist in your code). You've decalred the public class `CustomerConstructorTestProgram` where the `public Customer(String initName)` becomes a method and not a constructor! For that, you need to create a separate `Customer` class or modify the class name!
2. The class should contain the members i.e, in your case the 3 variables `name, age, money` (again missing in your code)

So, I will provide you with 2 possible solutions! Choose the way you need it for your use.

Solution 1 : Unified use of class

```
public class Customer
{
    String name;
    int age;
    float money;

    public Customer(String initName)
    {
        name = initName;
        age = 0;
        money = 0.0f;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Customer c1, c2, c3;

        // Create Bob
        c1 = new Customer("Bob");
        c1.age = 17;
        c1.money = 10;

        // Create Dottie
        c2 = new Customer("Dottie");
        c2.age = 3;
        c2.money = 0;

        // Create blank customer
        c3 = new Customer("Jane");

        System.out.println("Bob looks like this: " + c1.name + ", " +
                c1.age + ", " + c1.money);

        System.out.println("Dottie looks like this: " + c2.name + ", "
                + c2.age + ", " + c2.money);

        System.out.println("Customer 3 looks like this: " + c3.name +
                ", " + c3.age + ", " + c3.money);
    }
}
```

Solution 2 : Separation of classes

```
class Customer
{
    String name;
    int age;
    float money;

    public Customer(String initName)
    {
        name = initName;
        age = 0;
        money = 0.0f;
    }
}

public class CustomerConstructorTestProgram
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Customer c1, c2, c3;

        // Create Bob
        c1 = new Customer("Bob");
        c1.age = 17;
        c1.money = 10;

        // Create Dottie
        c2 = new Customer("Dottie");
        c2.age = 3;
        c2.money = 0;

        // Create blank customer
        c3 = new Customer("Jane");

        System.out.println("Bob looks like this: " + c1.name + ", " +
                c1.age + ", " + c1.money);

        System.out.println("Dottie looks like this: " + c2.name + ", "
                + c2.age + ", " + c2.money);

        System.out.println("Customer 3 looks like this: " + c3.name +
                ", " + c3.age + ", " + c3.money);
    }
}
```